# how to hide blank space between textboxes when one of them is conditionally invisible in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

My SSRS report has five text boxes, each arranged one below the other. The third text box has a visibility condition which will hide the text box in a few cases. Under such cases, there is a blank space shown between the first two and the last two boxes. Is there a way to hide this blank space without re-ordering them?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Try using multiple expressions in the same textbox. It should give you the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click at the left hand edge of the tablix, you will find there is a 'Row Visibility' property.

Answer (score 0):

Put the text box that you want to hide/show conditionally in it's own row, then hide/show the row, instead of the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Like others were saying, you could combine them all into one textbox. It would look something like this:

`=IIF(showText1 = true, vbcrlf & "Text 1" &, "") & IIF(showText2 = true, vbcrlf & "Text 2" &, "") & IIF(showText3 = true, vbcrlf & "Text 3" &, "")`

Note: You'll probably want "Allow height to increase" and "Allow height to decrease" checked in your textbox properties as well when doing this